# OpenLayers zoomToExtent does not zoom correctly

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have an openlayers map with a couple of POI, and I want to zoom so these all fit the map, which I'm doing with the following code:

```
var bbox = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
    <?php echo $this->box->getSmallestLongitude() ?>,
    <?php echo $this->box->getSmallestLatitude() ?>,
    <?php echo $this->box->getLargestLongitude() ?>,
    <?php echo $this->box->getLargestLatitude() ?>
).transform(map.displayProjection, map.projection);
map.zoomToExtent(bbox);
//normally zoom is auto, but for some reason it zooms to 0...
//manual zoom looks like a correct workaround
map.zoomTo(map.getZoomForExtent(bbox));
```

Now as you may already have noticed: I have to `map.zoomTo` manually; since the `map.zoomToExtent` does set the center correct; but zooms to 0....

Any ideas as to why it won't calculate the zoom correct the first time?

Comment: what are your projections? Do you have proj4js loaded?

Comment: Well since the second call works, I guess everything is OK? my colleague just told me we do not need proj4js?
We are going from EPSG 4326 to 900913

Comment: I had similar problem when using cached layers with fixed zoomlevels. zoomToExtent didn't work. I used map.setCenter(lonlat,zoomlevel) instead. I guess it had something to do with the fact that open layers couldn't zoom to that exact extent because it didn't match any zoomlevel.

Comment: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.6/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Projection-js.html. First line on taht page says that it depends on proj4js. But I'm not sure.

Comment: In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddie_d_2000/KrMLf/)  it is working.